# Best way for Flex to communicate with C# backend?

Tags: c#, apache-flex, http, soap, protocols

What is the best way for flex frontend to communicate with backend writted in C#? The only communication channel in HTTP, so no custom sockets.

I used SOAP in the past, but am concerned about performance since the large overhead of xml, and this application I'm currently working on will be pretty data intensive.

Anything that supports easy setup and transparent marshaling/unmarshaling is OK.

Is there something as BlazeDS for .net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a few options by googling AMF .NET and AMF C# (AMF is the protocol that BlazeDS uses)-

- [WebOrb for .NET](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html) (commercial)
- [FlourineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) (open source)
- [AMF.NET](http://amfnet.openmymind.net/) (open source - appears to be dead)

However, I haven't used any of these projects - I've just used Flex backed by Java and PHP.

Comment: +1 on WebOrb.  It gives you a bunch of great features for debugging.

Comment: +1 for WebOrb as well.  FlourineFX is also a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using JSON?

I don't know anything about flex tbh, so best I give you some links to look at:

www.json.org

flexexamples.blogspot.com/2007/12/flex-json-net-sample-application.html

www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/02/25/a-custom-converter-for-json-net.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I looked at it, but seems like it requires manual marshaling/unmarshaling to/from strings on both sides. I need something as transparent as SOAP.

Comment: JSON CAN work with Flex/AS3 but it is one of the slower and more painful possibilities.

Comment: There's JSON serializers for both sides so you don't have to do a lot of tedious work there.  There's a great post on how to do that here: http://www.thegrubbsian.com/2009/01/02/integrating-adobe-flex-and-net-with-aspnet-mvc/